# Rotated Textview not covering full page

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, textview, justify

I am using a TextView which has to rotate at angle at 35 degrees. I have successfully created a rotated textview but I can't fill the complete screen. Basically I want to complete 2 objectives-

1)**Make the textview occupy the whole screen**

currently it is showing it like this-[image: []

I wanna fill the space left in the top left corner. I covered the other three corners by the help of @Alexandre's answer. @Thanks Alexandre.

**CustomTextView.java**

```
public class CustomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec*2, heightMeasureSpec*3);
}
}
```

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.dakshansh.partytimevendorsapp.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="-35"
    <!--Hope I don't need to change text.Text is too much more.-->
    android:text="Galleries" />
</LinearLayout>
```

2)**Make the text justified**

As you can see my text is left aligned & as I am trying to create a pattern, I would require the text to be justified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a CustomTextView that extends TextView overriding [onMeasure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int, int)).

For example :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec*2, heightMeasureSpec*2);
}
```

This would make your textView 4 times bigger filling the white spaces.

PS: I haven't tried this code.

Comment: It did so but partially, all blank space on the top has been covered well but there is some space still left in the bottom

Comment: You can try to set negative margins to your view to fill the empty spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alexandre